# Fetching more then 1200 items is not possible in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to fetch more then 1200 records from a query in GAE but this fails, just keeps loading forever. I can see in the debug that it keeps doing GET requests to Google but I never see any results

This works perfectly:
for lcr in deactivation_list.fetch(1200,offset=0, batch_size=1000):

This keeps loading:
for lcr in deactivation_list.fetch(1201,offset=0, batch_size=1000):

Tried increasing the batchsize, didnt help. I'm using NDB models

Comment: see the offcial help about the correct way for pagination. using offset is very inneficient and you are likely reaching timeout.

Comment: The offset is 0? There must be a reason it's always exactly returning 1200 records and then just keeps loading? Doesnt feel like a timeout?

Comment: true. ignore my previous comment. tell us how big is each entity. also try getting 1200 with offset=1 to test what happens

Comment: Tried that, works. With offset 500 it doesnt. Same symptons...

Comment: Is this running locally, against the dev server? That's just a simulation of the real datastore, and has always had problems with >1000 items. It should work in production.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is to use cursors, as suggested in the comments earlier. The reason is that the Google Remote API has a 1mb limit, using cursors you can query it multiple times.

recordQuery = model.query()

```
record, cursor, more = recordQuery.fetch_page(1000)
while more:
    record, cursor, more = recordQuery.fetch_page(1000, start_cursor=cursor)
```